# Remove unneeded whitespaces in Jinja template without HTML

Tags: jinja2

I wrote a Jinja template:

```
ФИО: {{ fullname }}

{% for task, fact_hours, plan_hours in week_results %}
    {%- if fact_hours != 0 and plan_hours != 0 -%}
Задача №:{{ task.id }} "{{ task.name }}"
    Фактическое время: {{ fact_hours }}
    Планируемое время: {{ plan_hours }}
        {%- if fact_hours <= plan_hours %}
    Соответствует графику
        {%- else %}
    НЕ соответствует графику
        {%- endif +%}

    {% endif %}
{%- endfor %}
```

It's rendering data this way:

```
ФИО: Оксана Викторовна Абракадабровна

Задача №:511 "Доработки PlanFix"
    Фактическое время: 3.0
    Планируемое время: 3.0
    Соответствует графику

    Задача №:8710 "Аналитика поступлений и затрат"
    Фактическое время: 0.8
    Планируемое время: 2.0
    Соответствует графику

    Задача №:8753 "0. Сопровождение клиента"
    Фактическое время: 2.2
    Планируемое время: 2.5
    Соответствует графику
```

I want to reach this format:

```
ФИО: Оксана Владимировна Абракадабровна

Задача №:511 "Доработки PlanFix"
    Фактическое время: 3.0
    Планируемое время: 3.0
    Соответствует графику

Задача №:8710 "Аналитика поступлений и затрат"
    Фактическое время: 0.8
    Планируемое время: 2.0
    Соответствует графику

Задача №:8753 "0. Сопровождение клиента"
    Фактическое время: 2.2
    Планируемое время: 2.5
    Соответствует графику
```

In other words, I need to remove the tab before the first line of each loop iteration. By the way, I don't really understand why the tab doesn't show for the first iteration.
Can I reach this without using HTLM tags?

I tried to wrap the line in `block` and append `-`:

```
{%- block loop_item scoped -%}Задача №:{{ task.id }} "{{ task.name }}"{%- endblock -%}
```

but it seems like whitespace controls doesn't work on a `block`.

**Caveat**: it prints empty lines when `{%- if fact_hours != 0 and plan_hours != 0 -%}` is `False`.

So, I'm trying to print nothing in this case.
For example, with the template:

```
ФИО: {{ fullname }}

{% for task, fact_hours, plan_hours in week_results %}
    {%- if fact_hours != 0 and plan_hours != 0 -%}
Задача №:{{ task.id }} "{{ task.name }}"
    Фактическое время: {{ fact_hours }}
    Планируемое время: {{ plan_hours }}
        {%- if fact_hours <= plan_hours %}
    Соответствует графику
        {%- else %}
    НЕ соответствует графику
        {%- endif %}
    {%- else -%}
        {{ '' }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

It outputs:

```
ФИО: Оксана Владимировна Бабенко

Задача №:511 "Доработки PlanFix"
    Фактическое время: 3.0
    Планируемое время: 3.0
    Соответствует графику

    
Задача №:8710 "Аналитика поступлений и затрат"
    Фактическое время: 0.8
    Планируемое время: 2.0
    Соответствует графику
Задача №:8753 "0. Сопровождение клиента"
    Фактическое время: 2.2
    Планируемое время: 2.5
    Соответствует графику
Задача №:9381 "1. Разработка органиграммы компании с описанием функционала и разделением ответственности"
    Фактическое время: 2.5
    Планируемое время: 7.0
    Соответствует графику

    

    

    

    

    

    
Задача №:9416 "3. Создание рабочего календаря технического директора"
    Фактическое время: 1.7
    Планируемое время: 2.0
    Соответствует графику
Задача №:9417 "5. Сопровождение внедрения изменений в работу отдела продаж"
    Фактическое время: 0.8
    Планируемое время: 2.0
    Соответствует графику
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of the whitespace control you added to the really last `endfor`, which is effectively removing the normal new line and leaves you with the spaces artificially created by the `+` in the `{%- endif +%}`.

Remove them both and you should be good for that part.

Then, to get rid of the blank lines when the condition `if fact_hours != 0 and plan_hours != 0` is `False`, use a [`for ... if ...`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#for) syntax.

> Unlike in Python, it’s not possible to break or continue in a loop. You can, however, filter the sequence during iteration, which allows you to skip items. The following example skips all the users which are hidden:
>
> ```
> {% for user in users if not user.hidden %}
>     <li>{{ user.username|e }}</li>
> {% endfor %}
> ```

<sup>*Source: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#for*</sup>

So, given the template:

```
ФИО: {{ fullname }}

{% 
  for task, fact_hours, plan_hours in week_results 
    if fact_hours != 0 and plan_hours != 0 
-%}
Задача №:{{ task.id }} "{{ task.name }}"
    Фактическое время: {{ fact_hours }}
    Планируемое время: {{ plan_hours }}
        {%- if fact_hours <= plan_hours %}
    Соответствует графику
        {%- else %}
    НЕ соответствует графику
        {%- endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

It effectively gives your expected output:

```
ФИО: Оксана Викторовна Абракадабровна

Задача №:511 "Доработки PlanFix"
    Фактическое время: 3.0
    Планируемое время: 3.0
    Соответствует графику
    
Задача №:8710 "Аналитика поступлений и затрат"
    Фактическое время: 0.8
    Планируемое время: 2.0
    Соответствует графику
    
Задача №:8753 "0. Сопровождение клиента"
    Фактическое время: 2.2
    Планируемое время: 2.5
    Соответствует графику
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's rendering a lot of empty lines when `{%- if fact_hours != 0 and plan_hours != 0 -%}` condition is `False`, that's why i inserted `-` in `endfor`. I tried add `{%- else -%}` to don't render anything in this case, but no changes

Comment: Then the trick is to use a `for ... if ...` answer edited accordingly.